# upgrade 4.0.17 to 4.1 version

Tags: processmaker

How to upgrade an earlier version to the latest?

I am running 4.0.17 (bitnami) version and trying to start using the latest 4.1 version. Platform Debian.

1. Unpack 4.1 files
2. CD into the folder and run `composer update --no-dev`
3. Copied .env file from 4.0.17 version backup
4. Install javascript assets using `npm install`
5. Compile javascript assets using `npm run dev`

Has anyone seen any upgrade steps? I am only getting error 500 in the browser. How to get access to detailed error logging to get more detailed error messages?

Comment: what are errors

Comment: @KetZoomer Very good and appropiate question. This is my first time when I trying to do anything with processmaker, so I am not familiar where to get access to error logging. After upgrade I did get error 500, but that don't tell anything to anyone. Will update question.

Answer (score 0):

I was encountering similar issues when trying to upgrade the Processmaker 4 AMI to the latest version. After some trial and error and a bit of help from folks with experience in laravel, I seem to have resolved *most* issues with my processmaker upgrade. These are the full steps I used to upgrade the AMI:

```
sudo su - bitnami
cd /opt/bitnami
sudo wget https://github.com/ProcessMaker/processmaker/releases/download/v4.1.0/pm4.1.tar.gz 
sudo ./ctlscript.sh stop
sudo mv processmaker/ processmaker-old/
sudo tar -xzvf pm4.1.tar.gz -C .
sudo cp processmaker-old/.env processmaker/
sudo cp processmaker-old/laravel-echo-server.json processmaker/ 
sudo cp /opt/bitnami/processmaker-old/storage/oauth-p* /opt/bitnami/processmaker/storage/
sudo cp -R /opt/bitnami/processmaker-old/storage/app/* /opt/bitnami/processmaker/storage/app/
sudo chown -R bitnami:daemon processmaker/
cd processmaker/
composer install --no-dev
npm install
npm run dev
sudo find /opt/bitnami/processmaker/ | sudo xargs sudo chmod a+w
php artisan migrate
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start
```

My current sticking point is that previously uploaded media is not getting displayed on the site, but I am no longer getting errors with laravel-echo-server or MySQL.

Aside from the files which needed to be copied from the old installation (`.env`, `laravel-echo-server.json`, oauth keys and app data) The biggest hurdle for me here was `php artisan migrate`, which modifies tables in the processmaker database to support changes in laravel/processmaker.